# this is c++ program i am not getting the reason why i am getting right answer how the value of counter is more than "i ".counter should start from 0?

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Shop
{
    int Item_ID[100];
    int Item_price[100];
    int counter;

public:
    void initiate_counter()
    {
        counter = 0;
    };
    void set_price();
    void display_price();
};
void Shop ::set_price()
{
    cout << "Enter the ID of the item  " << counter + 1 << endl;
    cin >> Item_ID[counter];
    cout << "Enter the price of the item : " << endl;
    cin >> Item_price[counter];
    counter++;
}
void Shop ::display_price()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        cout << "The price of the time with ID " << Item_ID[i] << " is " << Item_price[i] << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Shop dukaan;
    dukaan.initiate_counter();
    dukaan.set_price();
    dukaan.set_price();
    dukaan.set_price();
    dukaan.display_price();

    return 0;
}
```

i have written a simple code there are two member function set_price and display_price in which their is counter private variable but i am confused that how is counter value is more than i which is defined in for loop the output is correct according to me but how is it coming i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The `set_price` function does `counter++`. You call `set_price` three times, which will increase `counter` three times from `0` to `3`.

In `display_price` you loop while `i < counter`. Since `i` starts at `0` it will loop three times. Each loop will then print the corresponding data from your arrays (for example it will print `Item_ID[0]` in the first loop, `Item_ID[1]` in the second and `Item_ID[2]` in the third).